# ViewPager in fragment Class is not working properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-nested-fragment

Am using ViewPager inside the Fragment class.In that ViewPager have three pages in each pages am show customized list view.ViewPager Some time shows the list view properly in some time it shows blank page.

**Fragment class with ViewPager**

```
public class Schedule extends Fragment{

RelativeLayout schedule_lay;
Schedule_fragment_adapter sfadp;
ViewPager pager;
TitlePageIndicator tpi;
PagerTabStrip pts;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    schedule_lay = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule, container, false);
    pager = (ViewPager) schedule_lay.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pts = (PagerTabStrip)schedule_lay.findViewById(R.id.page_title_indicator);
    pts.setDrawFullUnderline(false);

    pts.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
    pts.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ff3824"));

    initialisePaging();

    return schedule_lay;
}

private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Ongoing.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Upcoming.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), Recent.class.getName()));
    this.sfadp  = new Schedule_fragment_adapter(super.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    pager.setAdapter(this.sfadp);
}
}
```

**FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
public class Schedule_fragment_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public Schedule_fragment_adapter(FragmentManager fm,
        List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return "Ongoing";
    case 1:
        return "Upcoming";
    case 2:
        return "Recent";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

**Customized list view Class**(My all three customized list class like below class )

```
 public class Ongoing extends Fragment{

RelativeLayout ongoing_lay;
ListView ongoing_matches_lv;
ArrayList<Item> ongoing_matches = new ArrayList<Item>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ongoing_lay = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.ongoing, container, false);


    return ongoing_lay;
}
}
```

Am not able find out my issue.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try using list fragments?

Comment: I had a similar issue while coming back from the last fragment the first fragment will go while and reload.I was pulling data from database and populating in the listview.

Comment: @playmaker420 did u get the solution for the issue

Comment: Yes.For my requirement that done the trick. May be there will be a fix for it

Comment: @playmaker420 see the Luksprog answer its work properly.

Comment: Upvoted! I was using Loader manager and simple cursor adapter so i didnt wanted to mess with that.I think my  problem was i was using Nested fragments

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [**`getChildFragmentManager()`**](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) instead of `super.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` when you instantiate the adapter at the line:

```
this.sfadp  = new Schedule_fragment_adapter(super.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

Comment: Thank you.Its Working fine.I have one more doubt.When i swipe this view pager.it was little bit slow.how can i improve it.

Comment: @Yugesh Either improve your layouts(to have fewer views and a shallow view hierarchy) or check if you're not doing any heavy initialization in the fragments that are used in the `ViewPager`. There isn't something obvious from the code you posted that would suggest something problematic.